# How to access the checkbox value from different frames?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a tkinter application where trying to get value from multiple checkboxes from different frames.When i am clicking the checkbox in one frame it is also checked in the other frame. I want to know how to access the checkbox value from different frames.

when trying to checking the checkbox (Tb1 in frame1) it is also checking in (NLTb1 in NLframe). I would like know how to access these two check box values separately.

```
from tkinter import *

def create_widgets_in_first_frame():


 task_type=Button(main_frame,text='Task Type',command=call_second_frame_on_top).grid(row=6,column=0,sticky=W)
 Network_Location=Button(main_frame,text='Network Location',command=call_third_frame_on_top).grid(row=7,column=0,sticky=W)

def create_widgets_in_second_frame():


 T1=Label(frame1,text="Verify and ensure there is no duplicate entries present in task type",bg='Light blue')
 T1.grid(row=3,columnspan=2,sticky=W)
 #creating checkbutton
 Tb1=Checkbutton(frame1,text='Pass',font=('Times New Roman',14),bg='Green')
 Tb1.grid(row=3,column=4,padx=6)
 #creating checkbuttonx
 r2=Checkbutton(frame1,text='Fail',font=('Times New Roman',14),bg='red')
 r2.grid(row=3,column=5,padx=6)
 #creating Run button
 b1=Button(frame1,text='Run').grid(row=3,column=6,padx=6)

 button=Button(frame1,text='Go to Main page',command=call_first_frame_on_top)
 button.grid(row=20,column=0,padx=6,sticky=W)

def create_widgets_in_third_frame():

 NL1=Label(NLframe,text="Verify the migrated Network location in NGMSS and ensure all the mandatory information's are migrated along with it",bg='Light blue')
 NL1.grid(row=3,columnspan=2,sticky=W)
 #creating checkbutton
 NLTb1=Checkbutton(NLframe,text='Pass',font=('Times New Roman',14),bg='Green')
 NLTb1.grid(row=3,column=4,padx=6)
 #creating checkbuttonx
 nbr2=Checkbutton(NLframe,text='Fail',font=('Times New Roman',14),bg='red')
 nbr2.grid(row=3,column=5,padx=6)
 #creating Run button
 nlb1=Button(NLframe,text='Run').grid(row=3,column=8)



 button=Button(NLframe,text='Go to Main page',command= call_first_frame_on_top)
 button.grid(row=20,column=0,padx=6,sticky=W)


def call_first_frame_on_top():

    frame1.grid_forget()
    NLframe.grid_forget()
    main_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W+E+N+S)

def call_second_frame_on_top():

    NLframe.grid_forget()
    main_frame.grid_forget()
    frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W+N+E+S)

def call_third_frame_on_top():

    NLframe.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W+N+E+S)
    frame1.grid_forget()
    main_frame.grid_forget()


def quit_program():
    root_window.destroy()

def raise_frame():
    main_frame.tkraise()

root= Tk()

main_frame=Frame(root,height=30,width=500,borderwidth=10,bg='Powder Blue',highlightthickness=10,highlightcolor="red")
main_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W+E+N+S)


frame1=Frame(root,height=30,width=500,borderwidth=10,bg='Powder Blue',highlightthickness=10,highlightcolor="red")
frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W+N+E+S)

NLframe=Frame(root,height=30,width=500,borderwidth=10,bg='Powder Blue',highlightthickness=5,highlightcolor="red")
NLframe.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W+N+E+S)


create_widgets_in_third_frame()
create_widgets_in_second_frame()
create_widgets_in_first_frame()


frame1.grid_forget()
NLframe.grid_forget()
raise_frame()

root.mainloop()
`
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, in your `quit_program` function, you call for `root_window` to be destroyed. You never defined this prior. My guess is you mean root.destroy()?

**Secondly**, I would say you might want to consider using radio buttons instead of checkboxes. Radio buttons will exclusively allow one option to be checked. This would prevent you from checking both the Pass and the Fail box on the same page.

As far as question is concerned, the reason your checkboxes are staying checked in the other frame because you are only forgetting the grid and not destroying the widgets. The grid is just what is organizing the widgets, not the actual widgets themselves. Therefore when you forget the grid and move to a new frame, the widget in that grid spot retains its state. Thats not to say destroying the widgets is the solution however.  To fix your problem just make sure that you are storing the state of the button in a variable. I've tweaked your code a little bit and got it working.

```
from tkinter import *


def create_widgets_in_first_frame():
    task_type = Button(main_frame, text='Task Type', command=call_second_frame_on_top).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
    Network_Location = Button(main_frame, text='Network Location', command=call_third_frame_on_top).grid(row=7,
                                                                                                         column=0,
                                                                                                         sticky=W)
def create_widgets_in_second_frame():
    t_var1 = BooleanVar()
    t_var2 = BooleanVar()

    T1 = Label(frame1, text="Verify and ensure there is no duplicate entries present in task type", bg='Light blue')
    T1.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    # creating checkbutton
    Tb1 = Checkbutton(frame1, text='Pass', font=('Times New Roman', 14), bg='Green', variable=t_var1)
    Tb1.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=6)
    # creating checkbuttonx
    r2 = Checkbutton(frame1, text='Fail', font=('Times New Roman', 14), bg='red', variable=t_var2)
    r2.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=6)
    # creating Run button
    b1 = Button(frame1, text='Run').grid(row=3, column=6, padx=6)

    button = Button(frame1, text='Go to Main page', command=call_first_frame_on_top)
    button.grid(row=20, column=0, padx=6, sticky=W)


def create_widgets_in_third_frame():
    nl_var1 = BooleanVar()
    nl_var2 = BooleanVar()

    NL1 = Label(NLframe,
                text="Verify the migrated Network location in NGMSS and ensure all the mandatory information's are migrated along with it",
                bg='Light blue')
    NL1.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    # creating checkbutton
    NLTb1 = Checkbutton(NLframe, text='Pass', font=('Times New Roman', 14), bg='Green', variable=nl_var1)
    NLTb1.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=6)

    # creating checkbuttonx
    nbr2 = Checkbutton(NLframe, text='Fail', font=('Times New Roman', 14), bg='red', variable=nl_var2)
    nbr2.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=6)

    # creating Run button
    nlb1 = Button(NLframe, text='Run').grid(row=3, column=8)

    button = Button(NLframe, text='Go to Main page', command=call_first_frame_on_top)
    button.grid(row=20, column=0, padx=6, sticky=W)


def call_first_frame_on_top():
    frame1.grid_forget()
    NLframe.grid_forget()
    main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E + N + S)


def call_second_frame_on_top():
    NLframe.grid_forget()
    main_frame.grid_forget()
    frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + N + E + S)


def call_third_frame_on_top():
    frame1.grid_forget()
    main_frame.grid_forget()
    NLframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + N + E + S)


def quit_program():
    root.destroy()


def raise_frame():
    main_frame.tkraise()


root = Tk()

main_frame = Frame(root, height=30, width=500, borderwidth=10, bg='Powder Blue', highlightthickness=10,
                   highlightcolor="red")
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E + N + S)

frame1 = Frame(root, height=30, width=500, borderwidth=10, bg='Powder Blue', highlightthickness=10,
               highlightcolor="red")
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + N + E + S)

NLframe = Frame(root, height=30, width=500, borderwidth=10, bg='Powder Blue', highlightthickness=5,
                highlightcolor="red")
NLframe.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W + N + E + S)

create_widgets_in_third_frame()
create_widgets_in_second_frame()
create_widgets_in_first_frame()

frame1.grid_forget()
NLframe.grid_forget()
raise_frame()

root.mainloop()
```

*Side note: In the future please take steps to make sure your code is readable and that you use proper naming conventions. You can find the [PEP 8 Style Guide here.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)*